# Trying to rebuild an older VB library. Dependencies are included but not accepted

Tags: c#, vb.net

To control a scanner array for Laser cutting I use Labview and a .NET DLL provided by the manufacturer.

Now I have to change one line in the Library.

Luckily I have the Project and source files. But when opening with Visual Studios some dependencies seem missing. I'm sure to have these files but their Properties are different to those expected.
For example their names include now an "Interlope." and they are Assemblies rather than ActiveX COM files. The version numbers do match.

I do have additionally one big *.ocx file that seems to be one of those missing Files. At least when included is shows the same properties and the missing one has to be deleted.

When including those files I am able to compile the class library and include it in my Labview program. There it is accepted and contains all wanted commands but ultimately does not work.
Also I get an "System.BadImageFormatException" error while compiling

The OCX file is registered with regserv32

I have no experience with ActiveX, .net, VB etc. Only programmed with C and Labview so far.

Comment: This is not simple.   Had similar issue a few years ago.  A lot of ActiveX object from VB2004 were obsoleted in VB2005.  Then there was VB2006, and then VB2008.  What version of VB are you using?  You tagged the question as VB.net which is VB2008 or newer.  We solved my issues by using VB2006 and registering the older VB2004 objects using regserv32.

Comment: I tried 2008, 2010, 2015.
I have no information oh what the original was build on, but I'll try that

Comment: Here how I fixed the problem:

I ignored the error. The Library was build anyway. 
Also to properly include the dependencies I had to delete the old one and add a new form in which I put in some parts out of the ocx file. The dependencies were added automaticly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I fixed the problem: I ignored the error. The Library was build anyway. Also to properly include the dependencies I had to delete the old one and add a new form in which I put in some parts out of the ocx file. The dependencies were added automatically.